# What can I do to display the function "size" inside the card?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

How can I display the size inside the card?
I can already get the size or the number of users and it does show correctly in the console. I'd like to know how to display the size inside the card. Also am I doing it right by using the function or should I use other ones? Thank you.

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function showNumOfUser() {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snap) => {
        const size = snap.size; // will return the collection size
        console.log(size);
      });
  }

  return (
    <Card
      style={{
        padding: ".5rem",
        marginRight: "1.5rem",
      }}
    >
      <Grid container spacing={4} className={classes.GridContainer}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
          <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
            <CardContent>
              <Typography
                className={classes.title}
                color="textSecondary"
                gutterBottom
              >
                <PeopleIcon style={{ color: green[500] }} /> Total Users
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="h4" component="h2">
                {size} // I want to display it here, but how?
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Link to="/Orders">
                <Button size="medium">
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="h2">
                    View All
                  </Typography>
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data fetching in react is usually done when the component is mounted, you achieve this with a combination of `useEffect` and `useState` hooks when writing functional components

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [size, setSize] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snap) => {
        setSize(snap.size)
      });
  }, [])

  return (
    <Card
      style={{
        padding: ".5rem",
        marginRight: "1.5rem",
      }}
    >
    ...
              <Typography variant="h4" component="h2">
                {size}
              </Typography>
    ...
    </Card>
  );
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html